# Adding new div into exist div with using onClick()

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid

Hi im trying to add into new div into exist div by clicking that div and i should do same thing for new div. For example, I have initial div, when i click it i created different div inside it. Then i click new div and i created new div inside it. I hope explanation is understandable =) Here is my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">

function run(id){

var id = $(id).attr("id");
document.getElementById(id).onclick = function () {
var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
   div.style.position = "absolute";
   div.style.left = "50px";
   div.style.top = "50px";
   div.style.height = "10px";
   div.style.width = "10px";

   document.getElementById(id).appendChild(div);
};

}


<style>

div.initial {
background-color:white;
width:400px;
height:30px;
}
</style>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class='initial' onclick='run(this)'>
      //new div will come here
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

The problem my javascript isnt working there is nothing when i click div with this code.

Comment: getElementById only returns one element, not sure why you act like it is an HTML Collection.

Comment: yes there is little mistake in there. I corrected it but same result.

Comment: Well what is `item`? That is not defined. Why are you binding onclick to an onclick?

Comment: That item<div class='initial' onclick='run(this)'>
      //new div will come here
    </div>

Comment: i edited some little mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea of what you are after.

```js
function run (){

  var div = document.createElement("div");  //create new div
  div.addEventListener("click", run);       //bind click to new div
  this.appendChild(div);                    //append the new div to clicked div
  this.removeEventListener("click", run);   //remove the original click event
  
}
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", run);  //bind the initial click event
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="start"></div>
```

Comment: This is actually what im trying to do. I think it is also possible adding two div inside one div with just one click, one left one right?

Comment: Yes, you would need to cancel the click and not remove the event.

Answer (score 0):

Here man:http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/gbuLykdj/2/

```
  <div class='initial'>
      //new div will come here
    </div>
```

JS

```
$('.initial').on('click',function(){
    var template = "<div class='newDiv'></div>";
    $('.initial').append(template);
})
```

CSS

```
div.initial {
background-color:white;
width:400px;
height:auto;
}

.newDiv{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:blue;
    margin:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function run, the parameter passed is an object javascript,  not an id of element, you could do this way

var id = $(id).attr("id");

Answer (score 0):

Oh, what an old version of jQuery you're using!! :( You would need to use a delegated click event using the jQuery `.live()` method. You may not be able to distinguish the new divs because (1) they are absolutely positioned (2) they have the same background color:

```
$('.initial').live('click', 'div', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $('<div/>').css({
        'background-color': 'black',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left':'50px',
        'top':'50px',
        'height': '10px',
        'width': '10px'
    })
    .appendTo( e.target );
});
```

```js
$('.initial').live('click', 'div', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var randomColor = ['black', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'gray'],
        randomN = Math.round( Math.random() * (randomColor.length - 1) );
    $('<div/>').css({
        'background-color': randomColor[ randomN ],
        'left':'25%',
        'top':'25%',
        'height': '60%',
        'width': '15%'
    })
    .appendTo( e.target );
});
```

```css
div.initial {
background-color:white;
width:400px;
height:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='initial'>
  click here:
</div>
```