# Add child div into parent div on click, then remove it on second click

Tags: javascript, toggle

In pure JavaScript, I have to add a child `<div>` inside of a container `<div>` using a `click` event. Then, I must remove each `<div>` on a *second click*.

Note: I already found the first half of what I need here, in the first answer to this question ...

[Adding new div into exist div with using onClick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383726/adding-new-div-into-exist-div-with-using-onclick)

... which is:

```
function run ()
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");  
    div.addEventListener("click", run);       
    this.appendChild(div);                    
    this.removeEventListener("click", run);  
}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", run);
```

How can I remove a div after adding it?

Comment: By second click you mean 'right click' or you mean 2nd click by count?

Comment: I mean by count

Comment: @Alex I added a late nuance. Be sure to check my answer again. Cheers!

Comment: @Alex, Does "second click" mean "double click"? Does "second click" describe a "toggle" operation, no double clicking required?

Comment: @ Anthony Rutledge yes it describes a toggle.And I resolved the problem.Thank you again

Comment: I voted for the answer as useful but my vote does not count

Comment: Ok, *now* that I know you mean *toggle*, check my answer. Is my answer similar to your solution?

Comment: Thank you for the vote. You are very kind. You could try selecting an answer that you like and solves the problem, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsbin.com/fehoxubumo/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
function run(e) {

//determine if the element clicked has been clicked previously
if(e.target.clicked) {
    e.target.clicked = false;   // reset "clicked" attribute
    while (e.target.firstChild) {  // delete all children by iteration.
    e.target.removeChild(e.target.firstChild);
   }
  }

// if target element has not been clicked before
// has been reset, 
// or this is the first time it is clicked:

  else if(!e.target.clicked || e.target.clicked === undefined) {

//create a div element 
    let div = document.createElement('div');
//append the new div to the target element
    e.target.appendChild(div);
//set the target attribute "clicked" to true.
    e.target.clicked = true;
  }
}

document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", run);
```

Comment: but can you view this and tell me what should I do when I want many nested divs as I said  https://jsbin.com/cikoma/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @Alex In the example I gave you the Divs are nested. I just had them positioned outside of the Div so you could see. I edited your code though and merged it with the code I provided. https://jsbin.com/noxenavehe/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so much time.Maybe I'm not explaining well. I have a div.when I click on it,there should appear another div inside.And when clicked on this child,still another one inside of this.So if I click on any of these boxes->child is born,and when clicked the second time->the parent is gone.   Anyway I think with what you had written I should be able to figure everything out.Thank you again

Comment: @zfrisch I voted for the answer as useful but my vote does not count

Comment: @Alex I'll update my answer in a little bit. I misunderstood at first, but I get it now.

Comment: @zfrisch Thank you

Comment: @zfrisch Apparently, he meant there should be a *toggle* effect.

Comment: @Alex Updated. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @zfrisch Yes this is exactly what was needed. Thank you very much,again.Also,if its not very hard can you help me redesign this a little bit.  Like I have this one parent div and when I click on it  some number of nested divs (50 divs inside each other for example) are created,and on second click on any of these divs only it is deleted without afecting its children

Comment: @Alex for that scenario I would suggest trying it out and posting a new question if you can't manage. You would need to append the target's child nodes to the target's parent, then remove the target.

Comment: just posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493837/nested-divs-that-can-be-deleted-on-click

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

**Update**: Alex says there should be a "toggle" effect for the child `<div>`.

It sounds like you could use one event `click` event handler on the *parent* `<div>` to accomplish the toggle. It just has to be a smart event handler. :-)

### Game Plan

I would use a technique called *event delegation*, here.

Create one event handler.

1) Name it `manageChildDivs(e)`, or something.

Assign `manageChildDivs(e)` to your ***parent*** `<div>`.

```
<div id="parentDiv">   <!-- Assign event handlers to parent div, here -->
    <div></div>
</div>
```

### Step 1:

First, adding a `<div>` with the `click` event on the parent is easy enough. Define the event handler. Remember, if you click a child `<div>` you just added, you do not want that event to append another `<div>` to the parent `<div>`! :-) You just want the *clicked* `<div>` (node) to be removed.

```
function manageChildDivs(e)  //Omitting old IE issues for a moment, etc ... 
{
    /* 
       I am just getting down to the nitty gritty, not giving an
       entire lecture on handling JavaScript events and browser issues.
       If you like jQuery, use that. This is just the skeleton.
    */

    if (e.target.getAttribute('id') === 'parentDiv')  //One way to do it.
    {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'deleteDiv');
        e.target.appendChild(div);
    }
    else
    {
        if ((e.target.tagName === 'DIV') &&
                (e.target.getAttribute('class') === 'deleteDiv') && //Test something.
                    confirm('Delete this element?'))   //Ok, just a bonus.
        {
            e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

### Step 2:

Lastly, add the event listener.

```
document.getElementById('parentDiv').addEventListner('click', 'manageChildDivs', false);
```

Generally, this is how I would solve this problem, because the number of child `<div>`s you could create is almost infinite. You do not want to allow the possibility of adding infinite event handlers.

I hope this helps. Add to it and you will be fine. Good luck.

Sincerely,

Anthony Rutledge

Comment: This seems reasonable, since the person asking seems to understand JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I understand(but not very deeply as noted),so can you please tell how do I write the code for targeting and removing the div that was clicked without removing the whole thing

Comment: @Alex This should help.