# Nested divs that can be deleted on click

Tags: javascript

I have a div and when user clicks on it 20 nested divs each inside of another should be appended.And when any of these divs is clicked it should disappear, without affecting its children.
[Nested div structure.When, for example, the 10th(highlighted with red) is clicked it should disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL7mH.png)

I'm sorry to bother you if the question is a trivial one. Thank you.

Code :

```js
 function run(e) {
   var div = document.createElement("div"); 
   div.setAttribute('class', 'Delete'); 
   div.addEventListener("click", run); 
   e.target.appendChild(div);
   this.removeEventListener("click", run); 
   e.stopPropagation()

}
function removeChildDiv(e)  
{
    if(e.target.className === 'Delete')  
    {
        e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
    } 
     document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", run);
}

 document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", run); 
 document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", removeChildDiv);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: @ putvande  https://jsfiddle.net/narekeranyan/v8n1wvu0/13/   this is a div and with click another div is created,but when clicked again its children are removed too

Comment: @ putvande so here is the code...whats next?

Comment: @Alex Let me know if the answer I provided is not what you needed.

Comment: @ zfrisch Good time of the day. Yes it isnt. I need a thing like this  https://jsbin.com/juyokolupe/edit?html,css,js,output   ,but mine isnt working properly.Like when  you click on any of these divs they are removed,but if the first click is on outermost div it doesnt work. I would appreciate very much if you can help me with this.

Comment: @Alex Updated my answer. Sorry for the wait. There was a space between your @ sign and my name so I wasn't notified that you had responded.

Comment: @zfrisch  Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsbin.com/mekumaralo/edit?html,css,js,output

```
var parentD = document.getElementById("1");
window.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = "div " + i;
    parentD.appendChild(div);
    parentD = div;
  }
}


function removeChildDiv(event) {

//if the parent is the body, we know this is the root Div element
//alternatively you could compare the node to the root and 
//store the root as a variable 
    if(event.target.parentNode == document.body) {

//if there is a child add the event listener to that child
//before removing the root div
    if (event.target.firstElementChild) {
      event.target.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", removeChildDiv);
    }
  }

  // changed to firstElementChild
  // firstChild will pick up text nodes, firstElementChild will not.
  while (event.target.firstElementChild) {
    event.target.parentNode.insertBefore(event.target.firstElementChild, event.target);
  }


  event.target.parentNode.removeChild(event.target);
}


parentD.addEventListener("click", removeChildDiv);
```